# Know how many customers have installed a Managed Package

Tags: managed-package

I've published a link of a Managed Package on a website.

It's possible to know how many customers have installed the package?

The only solution seems to create a patch and see on which customer I can push the changes but I wonder if there is a better solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you've assigned a LMO (License Management Organization) to the package, and installed the LMO app, you'll have a "licenses" object that shows every installation in a non-sandbox environment, which version they've installed, how many licenses they have, and when those licenses expire. You can even tell how many organizations have uninstalled the app and when. Sandboxes don't count, since they're not "active" orgs in the sense that they are neither trial orgs or production orgs. Note that the LMO doesn't need to be the APO (AppExchange Publishing Organization), which is the organization you publish from on the AppExchange, although in my experience, it's ideal to make them one and the same.